# Cannot make Vue route with param to work with component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

My own list of ideas, why route with parameter  is simply not recognized by  Vue and gives  me redirect to "/home" component is over.  Other simple routes work fine.

routes.js:

```
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";
import Login from "../components/login/Login.vue";
import Profile from "../components/profile/Profile.vue";
import ProductDetails from "../components/product/ProductDetails.vue";

import { partner_routes } from "../views/partner/routes";
import { purchase_routes } from "../views/purchase/routes";


import ProductCatalog from "@/views/product-catalog/ProductCatalog.vue";


const product_routes = [
  {
    path: "/product-catalog",
    name: "product-catalog",
    component: ProductCatalog,
  },
];



const routes = [

  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: '/product/:id',
    name: "ProductDetails",
    component: ProductDetails,
    // meta: {
    //   requiresAuth: true,
    // },
   },
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "Login",
    component: Login,
  },
  {
    path: "/profile",
    name: "Profile",
    component: Profile,
    // meta: {
    //   requiresAuth: true,
    // },
  },

];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes, // short for `routes: routes`
});
export default router;
```

Request for http://localhost:8080/product/1 gives me redirect to Home.

I suspect this code is not enough for troubleshooting, so is there any idea how i can debug routing? There must be $router.params somewhere, but i cannot figure where to catch it's value during runtime or where to set a breakpoint.
Thank you.

Comment: whats in `../components/product/ProductDetails.vue`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `beforeEnter` hook for debugging. Refer this [link](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard) for more router guards.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, Naren.
No, it doesnt' work.  Looks like  my problematic rote is not  even resolved.

Comment: Does your other routes work well?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to pass the `:id` parameter to the component using the route `props` config:

```
{
path: '/product/:id',
name: "ProductDetails",
component: ProductDetails,
props: true
}
```

`props: true`, passes current named parameters as props with the same name. In this case, it assues you have a prop 'id' in ProductDetails to read from.

Another way is to read the route param inside the component:

`$route.params.id`

Other alternatives can be found here:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

Comment: Hi, Igor. No, it doesnt' work. Looks like my problematic rote is not even resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it to work. I've added "mode: history" to "const router = new VueRouter(...)" and now new routes are being resolved. Still I have no idea why new routes (not even parametrized as it turned out later) don't work in hash mode while old routes like "/profile" work fine.
The urls I've tested did not contain a hash '#'.